# Approval process for external users (lightning experience)

Tags: lightning-experience, email-template, approval-process, digital-experience, approval-step

I have a standard approval process that needs to be approved by external users (experience site). When the approval process is kicks-off, an email is sent to the approver. I am merging the field on the email template `{{{ApprovalRequest.External_URL}}}` which looks like:

> https://abcurl.com/connect/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=04i8b00000I75Ue

However this takes the user to the classic site, not the lightning site.

Classic
[image]

Lightning
[image]

Is there a merge field that will take the user to the lightning experience in the site?
Do I need to create a special type of page in the site that with host this approval item?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this here is how I fixed it. I created a custom label and stored the URL for the community there. https://abcdefg.sandbox.my.site.com/abc then in the email template I call the custom label and add the rest of what I need to the end of it. So here is what I have in my template.

{!$Label.nameOfMyLabel}/s/detail/{!Workitem.ID}